# Ajax to reset some select boxes but not all

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have taken over the development of my companies website. When a select box value is changed in the card_filter div the following javascript runs.

```
      $("#cards_filter select").change(function(e) {
        var form = $(this);
        var serdata = form.serialize();
        var field_name = $(this).attr("name");
        var field_value = $(this).val();
        //Reset the selectors and keep the one that triggered filter
        $('#cards_filter').find('select').val(function(index,value){
            if($(this).attr("name") == field_name){
                return field_value;
            } else {
                return "-1";                    
            }
        });
      }
```

I would like it so the when the product select option does not get reset whereas collection, artist and category select boxes do get reset.

```
            <form id="cards_filter" method="post" action="" name="cards_filter">
                    <?php echo get_product_selector("products_filter"); ?>
                    <?php echo get_collection_selector("products_filter"); ?>
                    <?php echo get_artist_selector("products_filter"); ?>
                    <?php echo get_category_selector("products_filter"); ?>
            </form>
```

And the following function is in the library for each selector

```
function get_product_selector($form_name) {
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']['cur_product'])) {
    $curr = $_SESSION['loggedin']['cur_product'];
} else {
    $curr = -1;
}
$rtn = "";
$rtn .= '<select id="product" name="product">';
$rtn .= '<option value="-1"';
if ($curr == -1) {
    $rtn .= ' selected';
}
$rtn .= '>Select a Product</option>';
$DB = new mysql_db();
$DB->sql_connect();
$q = "SELECT * FROM type order by type_title asc";
$DB->query($q);
if ($DB->get_num_rows()) {
    $results = $DB->fetch_all_rows(MYSQL_ASSOC, NULL);
    foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
        $rtn .= '<option value="' . $row['Type_ID'] . '"';
        if ($curr == $row['Type_ID']) {
            $rtn .= ' selected';
        }
        $rtn .= '>' . trim($row['Type_Title']) . '</option>';
    }
}
$rtn .= '</select>';

return $rtn;
```

}

Comment: Assuming the `product` select has an id like `#product`, use `.not()` to exclude it `$('#cards_filter select').not('select#product').val(...)`

Comment: Post the related HTML markup and we can be more specific.

Comment: have added the markup. thanks

Comment: Nope, that's not the markup, but a lot of PHP code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#cards_filter select").on('change', function() {
    var serdata = $(this.form).serialize(),
        field_name = this.name,
        field_value = this.value;

    $("#cards_filter select").not('#product').val(function(index, value) {
        return this.name==field_name ? field_value : -1;
    });
});
```

Not sure I get it, but the change event is on a select box, yet you're serializing `this`, which is not the form but the select? Also it looks as the "product" select has the ID `#product`, so just exclude that from the selector where you're changing the value ?